# Observable subscribed but not returning values

Tags: angular, subscribe

I am trying to pass the value of a Subscription to a different component. Based on console logs I'm reaching the service fine, but not emitting from the service to the class?

Console logs from initial page load:

> watching lg sub in home.component
>
> svc pushed observable
>
> lg updated for home: 0
>
> svc set lg: 0

When I change the value I get:

> svc set lg: 2

I expected to see this also, but did not:

> lg updated for home: 2

**My service** (which receives the updated value and updates the subscription)

```
....
export class HeaderService {

    private _selectedLgSub = new BehaviorSubject<LicenseGroup>(new LicenseGroup());

    public _selectedLgObservable() {
        console.log('svc pushed observable') //happens once
        return this._selectedLgSub.asObservable();
    }

    public setLg(lg: LicenseGroup) {
        console.log('svc set lg: ' + lg.id)
        this._selectedLgSub.next(lg);
    }

}
```

**My component** (which is subscribed to the value):

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
    private _subLg: Subscription = new Subscription();
    constructor(public auth: AuthService, private router: Router, private headSvc: HeaderService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('watching lg sub in home.component')
        this._subLg = this.headSvc._selectedLgObservable().subscribe(lg => console.log('lg updated for home: ' + lg.id));
    }
    .....
```

Comment: where / how is the HeaderService provided?

Comment: Looks like default value of `lg.shortName` [i.e. when you initialize `BehavorSubject` with `new LicenseGroup()`] is `null` and when you set new `LicenseGroup` its `shortName` is empty. Can you please check?

Comment: @bryan60 I have a webpage running home.component.ts and header.component.ts both of which have headerService injected

Comment: @user2216584 that was bad data on my part- I corrected the output and updated the example to display the id value everywhere, rather than displaying the id and shortName value at different points in the code. Thanks!

Comment: So there is no problem anymore?

Comment: But where is it PROVIDED?

Comment: @bryan60, thanks your question lead me to my answer- I needed to call the service initially inside a component that was a parent of both the header and home. I wound up moving it to the app.component and it works